# Lisp Interpreter in java, dealing with genericity

Tags: java, generics

I am writing a Lisp interpreter in Java, and I am a little stuck on genericity within the language. I have a class `List` which is defined as such:

```
public class List<E extends Lisp> implements Lisp {

    private ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<>();

    List(){
    /* Constructor code goes here */
    }

    /*
    Other methods that deal with lists go here
    */

}
```

Lisp is just an interface I use as a common denominator for the two types within Lisp, Atoms and Lists. Since a list in Lisp can point to more lists as well as Atoms, I need to be able to store lists to lists through genericity, meaning that The `ArrayList` needs to be able to hold an object of type `List` and an object of type `Atom`. The problem arises when I try to extract the first member for the list, which in theory can be either a list or an atom I can't have two functions that have the same name and return different types. As such, the workaround I figured out was:

```
public E car(List<E> l) {

    if (l.list.get(0) instanceof Atom)
        return (E)(Atom) l.list.get(0);
    else
        return (E)(List<E>) l.list.get(0);
}
```

My thinking there is that if the object stored is of type `Atom`, cast it to an `Atom` and then to a generic Object E, Is there any other way around this issue?

Another issue, is when in the method `cons`, which is overloaded to have two definitions, one that looks like this:

```
public List<E> cons(List<E> l1, List<E> l2)
```

and another that looks like this:

```
    public List<E> cons(Atom a, List<E> l) {
        List<E> cons_list = new List<E>();

        cons_list.list.add(a);
        cons_list.list.addAll(l.list);

        return cons_list;
    }
```

The Interpreter/Compiler seems to think that `E` does not include `Atom`. Is there a fix to this? The error that eclipse is reporting is:

> The method add(E) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Atom)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Interpreter/Compiler seems to think that E does not include Atom. Is there a fix to this ?

At compile time, your program has no mean to know that `E` is an `Atom`. To have to pass another class test to make it work:

```
public List<E> cons(E a, List<E> l) {
    List<E> cons_list = new List<E>();

    if (a instanceof Atom)    {
        cons_list.list.add(a);
    }

    cons_list.list.addAll(l.list);

    return cons_list;
}
```

This should resolve your issue, as you try to add an `E` object to a  `List<E>`.

---

> My thinking there is that if the object stored is of type Atom, cast it to an Atom and then to a generic Object E, Is there any other way around this issue ?

Your assertion is correct. It is the same issue as what I previously said: if you try to cast it to `Atom` only your compiler won't let you run your program. However, I think your cast choice is useless: you have an object which is generic, but you **know** that it is an `Atom` when testing the class. I think you can reduce your method like this:

```
public E car(List<E> l) {

    if (l.list.get(0) instanceof Atom)
        // Your `E` is an Atom, you know this when coming then
        // Your list contains E's, so you don't have to cast it
        return l.list.get(0);
    else
        // Here you need the double cast, because you don't try
        // the actual class: it may be anything.
        return (E)(List<E>) l.list.get(0);
}
```

Watch out, in addition, to `ClassCastException` with your `else` statement. You may want to try if it is a `List<E>`, despite being sure that it can be either a `List` or an `Atom`.